# Keep a job running even after shell window has been closed

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a simple PS script to start or stop all my VM's hosted in Azure. Doing this sequentially takes forever, so I made this into a Job (i.e. each Start/Stop of the VM is a separate job).

Now the script executes much faster since each Start/Stop action is independent of the other, however if I close the PS shell window the jobs obviously stop and the action doesn't get performed on the VM. What I want is some sort of a "fire and forget" type of action, where I can just run the script, see that it has started executing the jobs then shut down my laptop and pack up.

Is this possible in PS to start a job even if the PS window has been closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following script executes as a job on the remote computer, in this example it writes the time to a file on the remote computer.

After starting the script I close the local powershell session and the script continues to execute on the remote computer indicating that what you require is indeed possible.

```
$computername = "mycomputer"
$script = {
    1..10 | %{ 
        "$_ $(get-date)" | out-file -FilePath "c:\temp\time.txt" -Append
        sleep 10
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock $script -AsJob
```

If you place the code that you would like executed in the remote machine in the script block then this will run on the remote computer without the need to keep the local session alive.

Comment: I thought of this too, and this will work fine when I want to stop the machine but it won't do for starting (since the machines will be powered off)

Comment: In which case you will need a machine between your laptop and the server(s) to orchestrate the starting of the machines.

Comment: Yea, thought so. Oh well, just thought I'll see if it could be done through powershell

Comment: This seems to be true only for remote jobs, not when running Invoke-Command locally.

Comment: @xdhmoore try adding the parameter -AsJob to do the same thing locally.

Comment: @DavidMartin Upon a second look, I think it's cause *all* my jobs seem to be failing after a while even with the console still open. Probably doing something wrong, but I don't have time to look into it now...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep a job running after main process finishes, you can simply invoke new powershell process. Something like this

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-command "& {gci c:\ -rec}"'
```

If needed, you can use -file command line argument and specify your ps1 which will be executed in separate process.

Comment: Its closing the process when powershell exits.

Comment: I tried it out, and it does close together with the main PowerShell session, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

Just come across this as having same issue, Add a loop to the end of your script..

```
do{  Start-Sleep 60  }  until ((get-job).State -notcontains 'running')
```

Comment: ...Aaaand when the window is closed, the command goes out with the window all the same.

Answer (score -2):

It may not help everyone, but I found that putting `try {} finally {}` in the job lets you run code in the finally block even after the window closes.

For my scenario, I was deleting a folder in a background job so it was easy to pick up the delete and continue it in the finally block.

Something like:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $Directory = "c:\temp"
    try
    {
        del $Directory
    }
    finally
    {
        # If the window was closed, continue deleting here
        if (Test-Path $Directory)
        {
            del $Directory
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I tested it and the finally block never deleted the directory if the window was closed. maybe your example should not also try to delete the directory in the try.
add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 5` in the middle and kill it in there and it will not delete